# Simulating Button click in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to stimulate the effect of clicking on button (submit button) through javascript or jQuery in a form.
I tried using `.click()` in jQuery but got no as such response.

In FireBug Events, I get the following events on the submit button of the form.

**mouseup** `{ return fn.apply(object, args); }`

```
function () {
return fn.apply(object, args);
}
```

**mousedown** `{ return fn.apply(object, args); }`

```
function () {
return fn.apply(object, args);
}
```

Well I don't know if  this information was useful anyway because both mouseup and mousedown seem to be same here.

The source of submit button appears like:

`<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />`

I have tried other methods to submit the form like `.submit()` but they did not work. I guess I am left over with stimulating click of button only.

Code:

```
$('#answer').val("chicago");

$(form).submit();
```

---

```
<form id="level" method="post"> 

<br/> 
<label for="answer">Answer:</label> 


<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" /> 

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /> 


</form>
```

Comment: I think you want to "simulate" the effect, rather than "stimulate" it. StackOverflow isn't *that* sort of site ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `<input>` is named `submit`, `form.submit` refers to your DOM element rather than the built-in `submit` function.

Rename your `<input>` and `form.submit()` will work fine

Comment: Well I can't, because it's an external form and I am using GreaseMonkey here.

Comment: Hmmm... Try `document.createElement("form").submit.call(form)`

Comment: Well, can you explain how it would fix? It did not b.t.w

Comment: This code calls the `submit` method from another `<form>` on your form.  I don't know why it wouldn't work.  Try setting the existing `<input>`'s `name` (although that may break the site, so you might want to set it back afterwards)

Comment: You can actually rename an input with GM. Something may break in the app, but maybe not. Just try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(form).submit();
```

That should do it.
http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Whoops, missed that you tried that already. Include you're actual javascript and the form element and I can maybe help you debug that.